# Android SDK manager cannot download samples of android

Tags: android, sample

I have downloaded the Eclipse IDE with built-in ADT (Android Developer Tools) of the latest version. Then I run the Android SDK manager to get the samples
as the picture descripted below:
Name                               API     Rev    Status
    Tools 
      Android SDK Tools                    22.0.1   Installed
      Android SDK Platform-tools           17       Installed
      Android SDK Build-tools              17       Installed
    Android 4.2.2(API17)
      SDK Platform                 17      2        Installed
      ARM EABI v7a System Imange   17      2        Installed
    Extras
      Android Support Library              13       Installed

There is no "uninstalled " options , So how can I get the samples and other uninstalled packages? 
   Thanks in advance!

Comment: the picture description did not display in the correct format

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, "https://dl-ssl.google.com/ " is banned from accessing because of some reasons. And based on the solutions from network I can resolve the problem.
The solution:

1. environment: WINDOWS 7,  Eclipse IDE with built-in ADT
2. find the file hosts from the directory"C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc"
3. edit the file hosts, append  "74.125.237.1 dl-ssl.google.com"
4. save the file
5. run the Android SDK manager.exe
6. choose the uninstalled packages and download them